# How access to parent and child nodes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using rc-tree, a version of tree.js to react, I dont know how create a method that when check on a tree item change a property of that element, parent items and their children items.

For example:

- If I click on New Folder1 change checked value on New Folder1 item,
  new Folder2, new Folder3 and finally, layer12.
- If I click on layer12 change checked value on layer12, New Folder3,
  New Folder2 and finally New Folder1.
- And If I click on new Folder2 change checked value on Folder2,
  Folder1, Folder3 and finally layer12.

Here is a json schema:

```
{
    "name": "New Folder1",
    "key": "0-625",
    "isLeaf": false,
    "type": "folder",
    "expanded": false,
    "checked": true,
    "children": [{
            "name": "New Folder2",
            "key": "0-629",
            "isLeaf": false,
            "type": "folder",
            "expanded": false,
            "checked": true,
            "children": [{
                "name": "New Folder3",
                "key": "0-623",
                "isLeaf": false,
                "type": "folder",
                "expanded": false,
                "checked": true,
                "children": [{
                    "name": "layer12",
                    "key": "0-99",
                    "isLeaf": true,
                    "type": "layer",
                    "checked": true
                }]
            }]
        }]
},
```

I found this method where find node when you check and item on tree. But how to change their children nodes and parent nodes.

```
function getNodeByKey(key, node){
    var reduce = [].reduce;
    function runner(result, node){
        if(result || !node) return result;
        return node.key === key && node || //is this the proper node?
            runner(null, node.children) || //process this nodes children
            reduce.call(Object(node), runner, result);  //maybe this is some ArrayLike Structure
    }
    return runner(null, node);
}
```

EDIT:

In React you need to use the ref property in order to access the node element and then you can access the child and parent using javascript: reactjs

To access child and parent I guess that I have to use `childNodes`, `parentNode`, `nextSibling` and `previousSibling`.

But how can use ref property??? Because its an array of nodes

```
render() {
    const loop = (data) => {
        return data.map((item) => {
            if (item.children && item.children.length) {
                return <TreeNode ref={this.myRef} title={item.name} key={item.key} checked={item.checked} >{loop(item.children)}</TreeNode>;
            }
            return (
                <TreeNode ref={this.myRef} title={item.name} key={item.key} isLeaf={item.isLeaf} checked={item.checked}  />
            );
        });
    };
    return (
        <div className="draggable-container">
            <Tree
                // Expand
                expandedKeys={this.state.expandedKeys}
                onExpand={this.onExpand} autoExpandParent={this.state.autoExpandParent}
                // Draggable
                draggable
                onDragStart={this.onDragStart}
                onDragEnter={this.onDragEnter}
                onDrop={this.onDrop}
                // Select && Check
                onSelect={this.onSelect}
                checkable onCheck={this.onCheck} checkedKeys={this.state.checkedKeys} >
                { loop(this.state.treeData) }
            </Tree>
        </div>  
    );
}

onCheck = (checkedKeys, event) => {
   how can get node checked??? it always returns last node
   const node = this.myRef.current;
   console.log(node)
}
```

Comment: You need to ask a question here. It's not clear what is working vs what isn't and what you need assistance with

Comment: sorry... I'll edited question

Comment: In React you need to use the `ref` property in order to access the node element and then you can access the child and parent using javascript: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Why always returns last ref??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... regarding your 'ref' issue: you assigned them all to the same variable, you should generate ref-variable for each node:

```
 this.myRefs = {};

<TreeNode ref={itemRef=>this.myRefs[item.key]=itemRef} title={item.name} key={item.key} checked={item.checked} >{loop(item.children)}</TreeNode>
```

So you can access each node by its key.

Another way to implement it would be to assign a more useful keys:

```
{
    "name": "New Folder1",
    "key": "0",
    "isLeaf": false,
    "type": "folder",
    "expanded": false,
    "checked": true,
    "children": [{
            "name": "New Folder2",
            "key": "0.0",
            "isLeaf": false,
            "type": "folder",
            "expanded": false,
            "checked": this.state.keysCheckedStatus['0.0'],
            "children": [{
                "name": "New Folder3",
                "key": "0.0.0",
                "isLeaf": false,
                "type": "folder",
                "expanded": false,
                "checked": this.state.keysCheckedStatus['0.0.0'],
                "children": [{
                    "name": "layer12",
                    "key": "0.0.0.0",
                    "isLeaf": true,
                    "type": "layer",
                    "checked":  this.state.keysCheckedStatus['0.0.0.0']
                },{
                    "name": "layer13",
                    "key": "0.0.0.1",
                    "isLeaf": true,
                    "type": "layer",
                    "checked":  this.state.keysCheckedStatus['0.0.0.1']
                }]
            }]
        }]
}

onCheck = (checkedKeys, event) => {
  let keysCheckedStatus = this.state.keysCheckedStatus;
   for(let key in checkedKeys){
      let connectedKeys= Object.keys(this.state.keysCheckedStatus)
                         .filter(k=> (k.length > key.length) && k.startsWith(key)) || (key.startsWith(k));
      for(let connectedKey in connectedKeys){
         keysCheckedStatus[connectedKey]=true;
      }
   }
  this.setState({keysCheckedStatus});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, because my idea is modify treeData with all tree info nodes:

```
onCheck = (checkedKeys, event) => {
    // console.log(this.treeData);
    const checkedKey = event.node.props.eventKey;
    this.updateItemChecked(checkedKey);
    this.setState({ checkedKeys: checkedKeys }, () => {
        this.props.parentTree(this.treeData);
    });
}

updateItemChecked = (key) => {
    var result = getNodeByKey(key, this.treeData);
    if (result.type.localeCompare('folder') !== 0) {
        if (result.checked === true ) {
            result.checked = false;
        } else {
            result.checked = true;     
        }
    } else {
        this.checkIfFolderHasItem(result);
    }

}

checkIfFolderHasItem = (result) => {
    if ( result.children && result.children.length > 0) {
        result.children.forEach( (item) => {
            if (item.type.localeCompare('folder') !== 0) {
                this.updateItemChecked(item.key);
            } else {
                this.checkIfFolderHasItem(item);
            }
        });
    }
}

// Expand
onExpand = (expandedKeys, event) => {
    // console.log('onExpand', expandedKeys);
    const checkedKey = event.node.props.eventKey;
    this.updateFolderExpanded(checkedKey);
    this.setState({ expandedKeys, autoExpandParent: false }, ()=> {
        this.props.parentTree(this.treeData);
    });
}

updateFolderExpanded = (key) => {
    var result = getNodeByKey(key, this.treeData);
    if (result.type.localeCompare('folder') === 0) {
        if (result.expanded === true ) {
            result.expanded = false;
        } else {
            result.expanded = true;     
        }
    }
}

render() {
    const loop = (data) => {
        return data.map((item) => {
            if (item.children && item.children.length) {
                return <TreeNode title={item.name} key={item.key} checked={item.checked} >{loop(item.children)}</TreeNode>;
            }
            return (
                <TreeNode title={item.name} key={item.key} isLeaf={item.isLeaf} checked={item.checked}  />
            );
        });
    };
    return (
        <div className="draggable-container">
            { 
                // (this.state.showModal) ? <TreeModal show={this.state.showModal} info={this.state.selected} treeData={this.state.treeData} parentTreeModal={this.doParentTreeModal} /> : null 
            }
            <Tree
                // Expand
                expandedKeys={this.state.expandedKeys}
                onExpand={this.onExpand} autoExpandParent={this.state.autoExpandParent}
                // Draggable
                draggable
                onDragStart={this.onDragStart}
                onDragEnter={this.onDragEnter}
                onDrop={this.onDrop}
                // Select && Check
                onSelect={this.onSelect}
                checkable onCheck={this.onCheck} checkedKeys={this.state.checkedKeys} >
                { loop(this.state.treeData) }
            </Tree>
        </div>  
    );
}
```

JSON Example:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Capas1",
        "key": "0-23",
        "isLeaf": false,
        "type": "folder",
        "expanded": true,
        "children": [{
                "name": "sectores",
                "key": "0-20",
                "isLeaf": true,
                "type": "layer",
                "checked": true
            },
            {
                "name": "distribucion",
                "key": "0-22",
                "isLeaf": true,
                "type": "layer",
                "checked": false
            }]
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Nueva Carpeta0",
        "key": "0-624",
        "isLeaf": false,
        "type": "folder",
        "expanded": false,
        "checked": false
    },
    {
        "name": "Nueva Carpeta1",
        "key": "0-625",
        "isLeaf": false,
        "type": "folder",
        "expanded": true,
        "children": [{
                "name": "Nueva Carpeta2",
                "key": "0-629",
                "isLeaf": false,
                "type": "folder",
                "expanded": true,
                "children": [{
                    "name": "Nueva Carpeta3",
                    "key": "0-623",
                    "isLeaf": false,
                    "type": "folder",
                    "expanded": true,
                    "children": [{
                        "name": "distribucion33",
                        "key": "0-99",
                        "isLeaf": true,
                        "type": "layer",
                        "checked": true
                    }]
                }]
            }]
    },
    {
        "name": "sectores1",
        "key": "0-27",
        "isLeaf": true,
        "type": "layer",
        "checked": true
    },
    {
        "name": "sectores12",
        "key": "0-89",
        "isLeaf": true,
        "type": "layer",
        "checked": false
    },
    {
        "name": "Capas 2",
        "key": "0-588",
        "isLeaf": false,
        "type": "folder",
        "expanded": false,
        "children": [{
            "name": "Capas 3",
            "key": "0-589",
            "isLeaf": false,
            "type": "folder",
            "expanded": false,
            "children": [{
                "name": "Prueba",
                "key": "0-36",
                "isLeaf": true,
                "type": "layer",
                "checked": false
                }]
            }]
    }
]
```